# Save Login Swift

Tags: swift

How can you do so when closing the application do not ask me again to enter email and password? I read about userdefaults and keychainwrapper, but I can not apply any. I do test after test and they ask me again to enter the credentials.

This is the login code:

```
class LogInViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate
{
    @IBOutlet weak var emailField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var passwordField: UITextField!

    @IBAction func Cancel(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }

    @IBAction func LogIn(_ sender: Any)
    {
        if  self.emailField.text == "" ||
            self.passwordField.text == ""
        {
            let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: "Por favor introduce email y contraseña", preferredStyle: .alert)
            let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
            alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
            self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
        } else
        {
            Auth.auth().signIn(withEmail: self.emailField.text!, password: self.passwordField.text!) { (user, error) in
                if error == nil
                {
                    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "HandleViewSegue")
                    self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
                } else
                {
                    let alertController = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let defaultAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alertController.addAction(defaultAction)
                    self.present(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool
    {
        emailField.resignFirstResponder()
        passwordField.resignFirstResponder()
        return (true)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
        self.emailField.delegate = self
        self.passwordField.delegate = self
    }
}
```

Comment: Your provided code does not include any mechanism to save the desired information. Neither in userdefaults nor in keychain

Comment: @Malik hi, thanks for the answer, that’s the detail I don’t not know  to implement it or where to place it, that’s why I leave the code.